# Vue.JS Image Cropper

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Пишу приложение на Vue.JS. Мне нужен компонент Image Cropper, в котором есть возможность экспортирования отредактированного изображения.
Я скачал JCrop. Но я не нашел этого.

У кого какие варианты?

Comment: нужна только обрезка?

Comment: Нет, я ведь написал. Мне также нужна возможность экспорта изображения.

Comment: это понятно, вопрос про функционал самого кроппера в плане возможностей изменения изображения

Comment: Да. В самом кроппере нужна только обрезка. Но я, кажется, нашел. Vue-Croppie.

Answer (score 0):

Ищите компоненты тут: [vuecomponents](https://vuecomponents.com/)

А так есть варианты:

- vue-croppie
- vue-crop